# The meaning and the usage of the expression "lui mettre le grappin dessus"

Tags: sens, usage

> Je ne vais pas laisser ce vaurien **lui mettre le grappin dessus** !

Q1. With this idiomatic expression, I'm more familiar with the construction "mettre le grappin ***sur***", but how does it compare to "lui mettre le grappin ***dessus***"?

Q2. Can you say "mettre le grappin sur ***quelque chose***" as well as "mettre le grappin sur ***quelqu'un***"?

Q3. I wonder if "mettre le grappin sur" is close in meaning to "mettre la main sur"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mettre le grappin sur quelqu'un
```

peut aussi s'employer dans le sens d'acquérir une emprise psychologique/émotionnelle sur une personne. L'expression laisse alors sous-entendre une séduction dans le but de tirer un bénéfice ou une emprise "totale" sur la personne (perte de liberté de la personne (é)prise).

Dans une utilisation plus littérale, il peut aussi s'agir d'attraper une personne ou une chose **et ne plus la lacher**. On se rapproche dans ce cas plus de l'expression "mettre la main sur", mais cette dernière s'emploie plutôt avec une notion de "trouvaille" (sans l'aspect péjoratif, donc), e.g.

```
Je n'arrive plus à mettre la main sur mon portefeuille. J'étais pourtant persuadé de l'avoir déposé ici.
```

Plus proche de "mettre le grappin sur quelque chose" (notion d'accaparement), je dirais plutôt "faire main basse sur" (autre expression péjorative)

```
Il a fait main basse/mis le grappin sur l'héritage.
```

Comment: l'expression dans le sens émotionnel est très peu utilisée dans les régions où j'ai vécu. Je soupçonne que ce soit un sens détourné de l'expression.

Comment: @Anne Aunyme Merci pour cette précision. J'ai ajouté plus de nuance à ma réponse. Cependant, il me semble que l'exemple repris dans la question fait justement référence au sens émotionnel.

Comment: @Anne Aunyme : par ailleurs, je viens de faire un tour sur le Web suite à votre remarque: le Wiktionnaire, expresso.fr vont plutôt dans mon sens, alors que reverso ajoute également "retenir contre son gré".

Comment: Même sens ici, chapitre commençant par "L'image s'utilise également...". http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/mettre-le-grappin-sur-quelque-chose-quelqu-un.php

Comment: Je ne pense pas que l'exemple de la question fasse référence au sens émotionnel. Bien entendu il est impossible d'en être sûr, mais un sens similaire à celui de la réponse de jilliagre (Celui qui se gare devant mon garage, je vais lui mettre le grappin dessus) me semble plus plausible (à cause de l'emploi du mot "vaurien").

Comment: C'est mon avis et je le partage. On ne parle pas ici de mettre le grappin sur un vaurien, mais d'aviter qu'un vaurien ne mette le grappin sur quelqu'un. Je présume qu'un vaurien ferait pire qu'attraper fermement (physiquement) une personne dans le sens de jlliagre. Il est donc logique de penser qu'on ici d'un lien émotionnel (une fille "bien comme il faut" qui se fait manipuler par un "vaurien" (parce qu'elle est amoureuse ou fascinée)). Impossible d'en être sûr son contexte, bien entendu.

Answer (score 3):

Q1: That's the same expression. *Je vais **mettre le grappin sur** celui qui se gare devant mon garage* can be rephrased *Celui qui se gare devant mon garage, je vais (lui) **mettre le grappin dessus***. In your example, the meaning is something like "I won't let this moron grasp it/her/him."

Q2: It is possible: *[Il avait dû mettre le grappin sur le magot de sa bourgeoise](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-m/470-mettre-le-grappin-sur-qque-chose-ou-qqun.html)*. When the target is inanimated, the dative pronoun is very rarely used: *Le butin, il a mis le grappin dessus* instead of *Le butin, il **lui** a mis le grappin dessus*. (Thanks to @eauquidort for this comment.)

Q3: Not really, ***mettre le grappin sur*** means to catch, to hook.

Comment: Hi. So when using a pronoun like "lui", you need to keep "dessus" as a replacement for "sur"? After all, the preposition "à" or "de" is omitted when using a pronoun. This is not the case with "sur", I suppose?

Comment: *Dessus* is here a "standalone" adverb (on the top) while *sur* is a preposition  so needs to be followed by something (on the top of...)

Comment: About Q3, I think the answer is yes (?). http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/des/synonymes/mettre+la+main+sur. @Alone-zee, you can also be interested by "avoir la mainmise". http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mainmise

Comment: @lemon The meanings do overlap indeed but IMHO *mettre la main sur* doesn't include the "hold/hook" part.

Comment: Édit suggéré: Mentionner que quand la chose sur laquelle on met le grapin est inanimée, le pronom datif n'apparaît que très rarement sur le verbe: "Le butin, il a mis le grappin dessus", plutôt que "Le butin, il lui a mis le grappin dessus"

Comment: Hi. In saying, "Laisse-moi te faire un petit topo clair afin qu'on ne **revienne** pas **dessus / là-dessus**", does "revenir dessus" sound just as idiomatic? I, for one, opt for "revenir là-dessus" almost by default.